# Building a web application that can switch between other applications seamlessly

Tags: html, css, web-applications, architecture

I have a project I am working on and need a little guidance.  My company has 6 different web applications where they all have a different login screen and different looks.  What we are trying to accomplish is having one platform where you login once and from the main dashboard you can seamlessly switch between all applications via dropdown menu.  How would I go about starting on something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Initially it sounds like you'd want a thin, fixed menu at the top of the page, and an iframe that contains the other web-apps. Authentication is another issue, as you'd need to be able to  handle user sessions for each web-app. If their username/passwords are the same across all web apps, you may be able to simultaneously log-in to each app using a single process, but maintaining variable session lengths etc. across all apps would be difficult.

Look into the iframe thing. The authentication problem depends heavily on whatever frameworks each app uses. Are you using .NET and Windows Authentication? That may simplify the problem significantly.

Comment: Right now we are purely JAVA

Comment: Do you know of any UI designs I can look at that I can get a basic design concept going?

Comment: It's almost tragically simple from a design perspective. How much experience do you have with web development?

Comment: I have 4 years of experience of web development. Just trying to come up with some mockups before development.  I am basically having to break down each application so that I have a sitemap of each one and then implement a dropdown or toggle element somewhere on all applications so that they can seamlessly switch and also look identical in UI.

Comment: Sounds to me like that would require entirely revamping each application separately to have a similar user experience. What you're asking is far from trivial :)